# Counting words in websites with curl commande

Tags: ubuntu, curl, grep

I'm having fun counting words in websites, I need to count how many times a word appeared on the main page of https website and and I use a couple of curl and grep commands but the results are not exact :
curl --silent https://xxxxxx.com | grep -c hello
curl --silent https://xxxxxx.com | grep -c -i -w hello

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using curl it returns the whole content of the website, grep only the word hello and wc to calculate the number of occurrences.

curl https://wwwww.com/ | grep -io hello | wc

If you have other ideas I'm interested, like using python, Web scraping, using other linux commands like use command wget instead of curl.

Have a nice week end